# Why does pluck only work with single attribute when using find_by_sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reasonably new to rails, started working with rails in December (on and off). I'm still struggling at times. Today i needed to create data for a pie chart and failed miserably at it. After a lot of googling what i ended up getting it to work was this:

```
@stats = Trip.joins(:destination).group("dest_name").order("sum(km) desc").pluck("de
st_name,sum(km)")
=> [["Kværnen", 94.0], ["Stenodden", 52.0], ....
```

Problem solved, but.... I have no problem with the fact that my first attempt did not work except that i fail to understand why it didn't and that scares me. I'm SQL based, i use find_by_sql a lot especially in index actions, so it should come as no surprise to anyone that my first attempt looked like this:

```
@stats = Trip.find_by_sql("select dest_name, sum(km) from trips inner join destinations on trips.destination_id = destinations.id group by dest_name order by sum(km) desc").pluck("dest_name,sum(km)")
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

The funny part is that i can pluck these fields as long as i only pluck one of them:

```
@stats = Trip.find_by_sql("select dest_name, sum(km) from trips inner join destinations on trips.destination_id = destinations.id group by dest_name order by sum(km) desc").pluck("sum(km)")
=> [94.0, 52.0, 35.0, 32.0, 32.0, 22.0, 12.0]
@stats = Trip.find_by_sql("select dest_name, sum(km) from trips inner join destinations on trips.destination_id = destinations.id group by dest_name order by sum(km) desc").pluck("dest_name")
=> ["Kværnen", "Stenodden", "Ristinge", "Marstal", "Svendborg", "Strynø Havn", "Vejlesø"]
```

If anyone can explain to me why i can pluck either of these attributes but not the both of them, I'll be grateful.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.1)
```

Comment: try `pluck('dest_name', 'sum(km)')` .

Comment: You are welcome, you may accept eux's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66561451/687142 which describes it in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trip.joins().group().order()` returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, [pluck](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) defines on `ActiveRecord`, it supports two params formats:

1. `pluck("dest_name, sum(km)")`,
2. `pluck("dest_name", "sum(km)")`

However, `Trip.find_by_sql()` returns an `Array`, [pluck](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/5.0.0/Enumerable:pluck) defines on `Enumerable`, it only supports params format: `pluck("dest_name", "sum(km)")`.

You could check `class` of results by `Trip.joins().group().order().class` and `Trip.find_by_sql().class`.

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing the core of my problem. I'm happy again.